# Meaning of きく耳をもたない

Tags: idioms, reading-comprehension

The children are painting. Sekiguchi has just criticised Yamada's picture and run away with it:

> 関口はあざけるように山田の絵をひらひらさせて**きく耳をもたない**
>   Sekiguchi made Yamada's picture flap like he was making fun of him and didn't hold his listening ears.

My translation is nonsense. Please help me to parse it correctly.

Comment: 聞く耳を持たない：相手の言うことを気にしないこととか、相手の言うことを聞く気がないこととかかな・・・　慣用句ですから、辞書を引いたら見つかるはずだと思いますね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

聞く耳を持たない - literal: doesn't have ears to listen

In this case Sekiguchi doesn't really want to listen to what Yamada has to say so he waves his picture and ignores him. How you want to translate it is up to you, one example could be:

> Sekiguchi flapped Yamada's picture in his face, ignoring what he said.